# Show that the series $\sum \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\left( 3-4n \right)\pi }{6}\right) }{2^{n}}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation, cauchy-sequences

Using the addition formula for the sine function I have managed to reduce this to a simpler form:
$$\sum \frac{\cos \frac{2n\pi }{3}}{2^{n}}$$
It is obvious here that it passes the n-th term convergence test. But what next?
I have applied Cauchy's root test, this is the result:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\sqrt[n]{\frac{\cos \frac{2n\pi }{3}}{2^{n}}}$$
For the numerator  being  a "constant", I have gotten that the limit is 
$\frac{1}{2}$, which in turn means that the series is convergent. Is my reasoning behind this correct?

Comment: I can't understand the downvote: the question is nicely and well redacted put. The OP shows a serious self effort and work....so what's the problem? Perhaps someone thinks the OP **must** be right otherwise he must be downvoted?! But then what to ask for?

Comment: @Timbuc: After flagging a dozen questions questions per day from people who do nothing more than cut-and-paste their homework problems, I'm happy to upvote anyone who puts in a bit of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going your way:

$$\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{\cos\frac{2n\pi}3}{2^n}\right|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]1}2=\frac12<1$$

and the series converges absolutely and thus converges.

Comment: Oh sure, the absolute value is what's been missing.

Comment: And if $n = 3,$ or and multiple of $3$, we have $\cos 2\pi = 1$. I think you want to bound the numerator to get your result. The $n$th root will still evaluate to $1$, but as written, the first equality is incorrect.

Comment: @amWhy I guess that's what the absolute value brackets are for :)

Comment: @amWhy is right, and if I were applying the original test, I should be taking the lim sup of that...and the outcome is the same, of course. Thanks.

Comment: Absolute value signs here were assumed to make the \cos always evaluate to positive $1/2$, which is incorrect. Of course, the absolute value sign restricts $1/2 \leq |\cos(2n\pi/3)|\leq 1$. You're welcome Timbuc!

Comment: I guess I should  have used the most formal form of the Cauchy test in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Use the comparison with geometric series

$$ \frac{|\sin \frac{\left( 3-4n \right)\pi }{6}| }{2^{n}}\le\left(\frac12\right)^n$$